# Exibir uma lista com os campos, relatandos os filmes e associados utilizando CROSS JOIN

Tags: oracle

Tenho três tabelas,  a tabela tb_filme, a tb_ator e a tb_ator_filme, preciso de um script que exiba a lista de todos os atores e filmes com eles associados, segue imagens para esclarecer

[image: Tabelas e registros do banco de dados]

E eu preciso que de um script que os exiba assim, utilizado CROSS JOIN

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem certeza que é cross join que precisa? O cross join não faz ligação nenhuma entre as tabelas. E você tem as ligações.
Experimente esta query:

```
select f.id_filme, f.nome_filme, a.id_ator, a.nome_ator
from tb_filme f join tb_ator_filme af
on (f.id_filme=af.id_filme)
join tb_ator a
on (a.id_ator = af.id_ator)
```

Ps: eu não tenho agora comigo BD para testar, mas acho que faz o que precisa